# How can I open a stored folder path?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

I've made a app for viewing images. Its a Universal app, but for now Im only going to support Win 8.1.

Upon startup the user is asked to select a folder. After selecting a folder I go thru all the files, and recursively go thru all the sub folders.

I want to save the path, so next time the user starts the app it starts with going thru the folder instead of asking the user to pick a folder.

I had a look at Windows.Storage, and I would expect it to have a "await OpenFolderAsync(string path)" (or something similar) but it does not.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

I've tried to serialize the StorageFolder with JSON, but it was complaining about not finding a constructor or whatnot. How can I save a StorageFolder as a setting so I can pick it up the next time the application launches?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reconstitute the permissions from the path. You need to cache the StorageFolder itself by using the [Windows.Storage.AccessCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.aspx) classes.

The StorageApplicationPermissions.[FutureAccessList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) provides random access to items that have been previously used. The [MostRecentlyUsedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.mostrecentlyusedlist.aspx) allows keeping a list of recently used locations.

For more details see [How to track recently used files and folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh972344(v=win.10).aspx) on MSDN

I discussed this in more detail in my blog entry at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/12/05/stray-from-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile.aspx

Comment: Hmm... okey, thanks for the link! I rewrote my question in case you misunderstood it. But can I serialize StorageFolder and save it to settings for me to pick ut up the next time I start the app?

Comment: Please see my edit... how can I save StorageFolder for the next time the user starts the application.

Comment: That is exactly what the access cache classes are for: Save the storage folder in one of them and you can get it back on later runs with permissions intact. There is no other way